# onClick in Button do not work use Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, binding, onclick

I started to learn Data Binding Library 
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

I can not understand what not so do.

android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="presenter"
        type="ua.com.it_st.ordersmanagers.activiteies.HistoryActivity"/>
</data>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:text="Start second activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="@{presenter::onHistoryClick}"
    />
```

```
public class HistoryActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements HistoryView {

    @InjectPresenter
    HistoryPresenter historyPresenter;

    ActivityHistoryBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_history);
    }

    public void onHistoryClick(View view) {
        Log.i("test ","test");
        binding.test.setText("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot to set the ViewModel to your binding. 
If you expect the `onClick` to be received in your activity, you have to do

```
binding.setPresenter(this)
```

although I would recommend calling the ViewModel in your XML file `viewModel` or `activity` (it's called presenter right now). 
If you want your `presenter` ot receive the `onClick`, change the ViewModel type in your layout from activity to presenter, implement the `onClick` method in your presenter, and do

```
binding.setPresenter(presenter)
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do this is receive the onClick in the activity itself then pass that event into the function (if any) in the view model. You can do that in the following steps

1- In layout file, make change as:-

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

2- In activity file, implement View.OnClickListener and register listener as 
    binding.test.setOnClickListener(this)

3- Override the onClick method as

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == binding.test){
        //any utility method calls then calling the fun of view model
        (yourViewModel).onHistoryClick();
     }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `binding.test` here?

Comment: we are registering the listener for the given button which has id "test"....since it's view model implementation so we are doing through binding (data binding)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but i'm curious why you suggest this is the "best" way?  Is it just easier to maintain?  Seems like setting the onClick attribute right inside the layout xml file involves less lines of code